# How to keep single regression line and color dot in ggscatter by group

Tags: r, plot, regression, ggpubr

I have the following code:

```
library(ggpubr)
df <- mtcars
ggscatter(df, x = "wt", y = "mpg",
          add = "reg.line",                         # Add regression line
          conf.int = TRUE,                          # Add confidence interval
          color = "cyl", palette = "jco",           # Color by groups "cyl"
          shape = "cyl"                             # Change point shape by groups "cyl"
          )+
  stat_cor(aes(color = cyl), label.x = 3)           # Add correlation coefficient
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image]

In that plot, there are  3 regression lines for each member of `cyl`.

I want to color the dot by `cyl` but only have a single regression line.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add the regression line manually using a `geom_smooth`:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
df <- mtcars
df$cyl <- factor(df$cyl)

ggscatter(df,
  x = "wt", y = "mpg",
  color = "cyl", palette = "jco", # Color by groups "cyl"
  shape = "cyl" # Change point shape by groups "cyl"
) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = "black") +
  stat_cor(label.x = 3)
```

[image]